# Rename the table Column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rename

I am trying to execute the following query. I don't have 'CrewID' column so in that case it will by pass update part of the script. but it gives error Invalid object CrewID'. Can you please tell me why it excute update part even my if condition does not matched. Is there is another way to do the same. I have the requirement where need to rename the column but before rename i have to copied data in other column and need to excute script many times.

```
if exists (select * from syscolumns where name ='CrewID' and id in (select id from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[WorkPlanAssignees]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1))
BEGIN   
update A set A.TempCrewID=B.ID from WorkPlanAssignees A inner join Crew B on A.CrewID=B.ID
END
```

Comment: I think that the only cause for this is that your condition, as is writed, match. Try replace the update part with a print sentence to ensure it.

Comment: Jonathan, I tried with print statement and it does not print that means it does not go within if block that's what I want but in case of update statement it tried to execute it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stored Procedure consist Add column, Update data for that column, and Select all data from that table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871246/stored-procedure-consist-add-column-update-data-for-that-column-and-select-all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is not executed line by line. It's compiled as a batch. At compile time, the column does not exists. So it gives an error. The IF is irrelevant.

Use dynamic SQL or let us know what you're trying to do.

And asked before:

[Stored Procedure consist Add column, Update data for that column, and Select all data from that table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871246/stored-procedure-consist-add-column-update-data-for-that-column-and-select-all/1871673#1871673)

Comment: Thanks... yes its Compiletime error. I think dynamic sql will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and found that in addition to using dynamic sql I could solve it by cross joining to a temp table that had only one row.  That caused the script compiler to not try to resolve the renamed column at compile time.  Below is an example of what I did to solve the issue without using dynamic SQL

```
select '1' as SomeText into #dummytable

update q set q.ValueTXT = convert(varchar(255), q.ValueTXTTMP) from [dbo].[SomeImportantTable] q cross join #dummytable p
```

Comment: That sometimes works (as the reference to the non existent table triggers deferred compilation) but I have found that it is not reliable. Sometimes the parser seems to process (and error on) the non existent column before getting to the non existent table.

Answer (score 0):

First you rename the old table:

```
ALTER TABLE orig_table_name RENAME TO tmp_table_name;
```

Then create the new table, based on the old table but with the updated column name:

```
CREATE TABLE orig_table_name (
  col_a INT
, col_b INT
);
```

Then copy the contents across from the original table.

```
 INSERT INTO orig_table_name(col_a, col_b)
SELECT col_a, colb
FROM tmp_table_name;
```

Lastly, drop the old table.

```
DROP TABLE tmp_table_name;
```

Wrapping all this in a BEGIN TRANSACTION; and COMMIT; is also probably a good idea.

Hope it helps.